# How to access cookies or request from a service? symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a service, which requires to get some information from the request.

I do not want to pass those values to the service all the time, so is it possible, that the service gets some information about the request and especially the cookies by himself?

```
class SomeService {
    public function someMethod() {
        // access request and cookies, whithout passing in those values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inject the `request` service then.

You surely have a service definition, modify it like this:

```
<service id="my_service" class="SomeService" scope="request">
    <argument type="service" id="request" />
</service>
```

Then in your class, create a __construct method that will receive the request object:

```
class SomeService 
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function someMethod() {
        $this->request->getSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably need to add scope="request" to the service element as well.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, starting from Symfony 2.4, you can easily inject the new `@request_stack` service.

From the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html):

> If you are trying to inject the request service, the simple solution
>   is to inject the `request_stack` service instead and access the current
>   Request by calling the `getCurrentRequest()` method (*see* [Injecting the
>   Request](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#book-container-request-stack))...

That should cover most cases.

`@request_stack` emulates a `@request` service that behaves like any other services in the app.

`@request` is a special service because it may need to be instantiated several times (in sub-requests typically).

More info on that: [Why not Inject the request Service?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#book-container-request-stack)